# Magento 2 Controller override not working

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, magento2.2, controllers

I have to override 2 controller 1 override is working and 1 override not working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword" type="\Copper\Customer\Controller\Auth\ForgotPassword" />
    <preference for="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost" type="\Copper\Customer\Controller\Auth\ForgotPasswordPost" />
</config>
```

While `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword` override is working just fine. `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost` is not overriding

Do anyone know Why ?

Controller **ForgotPasswordPost.php**

```
<?php
namespace Copper\Customer\Controller\Auth;

class ForgotPasswordPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello";die();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should check if any other module/extension is overriding the same controller action

Comment: there is no third party module installed

Comment: can you add your controller code here?

Comment: @Piyush updated question

Comment: Your code seems right , check the file name and path

Comment: @Piyush this is the File `app\code\Copper\Customer\Controller\Auth\ForgotPasswordPost.php`

Comment: We assume you've cleared cache, compiled, etc... after adding the second override, right?

Comment: Would `bin/magento setup:di:compile` fix this?

Comment: @RaulSanchez yes I did

Comment: @AlvinNguyen `bin/magento setup:di:compile` did not fix

Comment: @Piyush apparently everything was fine, the issue was Captcha was validated via observer and if incorrect/empty it was redirect from there only and I was trying to hit URL directly, and I was redirection back from observer only. did not even reaching controller.

Comment: I am glad everyone are so willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove \ form starting it will be worked 
\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword it should be like
Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword

Please try this **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword" type="Copper\Customer\Controller\Auth\ForgotPassword" />
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost" type="Copper\Customer\Controller\Auth\ForgotPasswordPost" />
</config>
```

Comment: tried with and without \ only `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPassword` override is working. `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost` is not overriding

Comment: Apparently everything was fine, the issue was Captcha was validated via observer and if incorrect/empty it was redirect from there only and I was trying to hit URL directly, and I was redirection back from observer only. did not even reaching controller.

Comment: ok so all working fine now?

Comment: yes, apparently it was working from the starting. its just the captcha observer is redirecting before reaching the controller method.

Comment: ok great......!

Comment: Thanks @NavinBhudiya it is also working for me!

Comment: @VikramKumar :)

Answer (score 1):

It's should working fine. There is the only one thing you may have not took into account is put di.xml file in correct area. So di.xml file should be located in app\code\Copper\Customer\etc

And another one thing. If you just want to override method or add new functional before/after to method, please use plugin system it is better way then preference.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: can you give hint how to use plugin for my situation, I have to redirect to `example.com/password-change-success` page instead of login page after successful password change.

Comment: I cannot use `beforeExecute` too early, don't know if `aroundExecute` is applicable and how can i deduct if password change was successful in `afterExecute` ?

Comment: Apparently everything was fine, the issue was Captcha was validated via observer and if incorrect/empty it was redirect from there only and I was trying to hit URL directly, and I was redirection back from observer only. did not even reaching controller., but I would like to know how to do this with plugin